# BIRT auto size grid to match the table

Tags: eclipse, birt

I am trying to create a bill notice with payment stub underneath as a BIRT report. 
My bill line items can be more than one. The report uses a gird layout with the bill line item information in a table.

I would like to

1 . get the table and the enclosing grid to expand as much as possible, if needed (without affecting the tear off stub position)

2. and if there is more line items it should spill over to the next page.

So, the first page layout is different from the next page(s) layout. Has anyone done something similar.

Please let me know how to acheive this in BIRT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you use relative sizing (percentages) instead of fixed dimensions in the "size" property (under the "General" properties) you should be fine.